# Não consigo mudar o verbose_name de um campo

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, aplicação-web

Estou programando uma agenda, e para isso, criei o modelo "Compromisso", que tem o código a seguir:

```
class Compromisso(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Nome")
    descricao = models.TextField(verbose_name="Descrição")
    data_criacao = models.DateField(default=datetime.today, blank=True, verbose_name="Data de criação")
    prazo_cumprimento = models.DateField(DateInput)
```

As migrações já foram realizadas e alteradas, e o verbose_name que o Django colocou como padrão para o campo "prazo_cumprimento" foi `django.forms.widgets.DateInput`. Quando coloco o argumento `verbose_name="Prazo de cumprimento"` e tento realizar a migração, esse erro acontece:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'verbose_name'
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citando a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names) em tradução livre:

> Cada campo, com exceção de ForeignKey, ManyToManyField e OneToOneField, recebe um primeiro argumento opcional - verbose name. Se o verbose name não é fornecido, Django vai automaticamente cria-lo utilizando o nome do campo convertendo underscores em espaços.

Logo quando você fez:

```
prazo_cumprimento = models.DateField(DateInput, verbose_name="Prazo de cumprimento")
```

O django entendeu que você ja definiu o verbose name como 'DateInput' por isso acacbou criando o verbose name como `django.forms.widgets.DateInput`.

O correto seria:

```
prazo_cumprimento = models.DateField('prazo_de_cumprimento')
```

Existe uma pergunta semelhante no [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826485/model-in-django-1-9-typeerror-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument-ver)

Comment: Entendo, é minha primeira vez mexendo com datas em modelos e acabei me confundindo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Deu certo, aqui. Mais uma vez, obrigado!